# Spring-boot local repository 2.7.5 not working

Tags: spring-boot

an attempt to work with local repository of spring-boot project
failing according to intellij, but project is compiling and dependencies exist.
is it possible the all is good , but intellij error flag is wrong ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project-manager</name>
    <description>project-manager</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <apache.poi.version>5.2.2</apache.poi.version>
        <fasterxml.jackson.version>2.14.1</fasterxml.jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ... dependencies
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

worked fine with central-repository on parent version 2.7.5

worked fine with local repository on parent 2.3.0-RELEASE

thanks.

Comment: We are in suspense awaiting to learn **which failure** happens. Probably unrelated but `<spring.messaging.version>6.0.3</spring.messaging.version>` is an indication that you are mixing different versions of Spring which is a very bad idea. Mixing different modules from different versions of a framework is always a bad idea.

Comment: thanks. updated clearer possible failure, spring-messaging is not used.

Answer (score 0):

in case someone get same issue , solution:
Intellij (v 2021.3.3)
press
"File | Invalidate Caches" fixed the issue.

[jetbrain support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221441?_ga=2.159583869.1129018102.1675154842-2113935150.1637588986&_gl=1*17v70g2*_ga*MjExMzkzNTE1MC4xNjM3NTg4OTg2*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY3NTMyNDAwMC42NC4xLjE2NzUzMjUwNzMuMC4wLjA.)